# MySQL - Search One field for Multiple Values

Tags: mysql, search

Tablename: tbl_person
Columns: id,name,bio

Sample Data: (id,name,bio)
1,Mike,Cambridge university degree in physics
2,Pete,Cambridge university degree in geology
3,Sam,Oxford university degree in geology

Problem:
I would like to create a (My'SQL') search that can take multiple values and search and match them in one column

Example:
specifically search for: cambridge geology
I would like it to return record 2,Pete
and not all the record (because they contain matching keywords cambridge,geology)

The search that I have so far is
**SELECT** * **FROM** tbl_person **WHERE** tbl_person.bio **IN** ('cambridge','geology')
 --Now this does not return a match--
Any Ideas please

Comment: Next time you can replace *does not work at all* with *does not return any match* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT * FROM tbl_person WHERE tbl_person.bio
    LIKE '%cambridge%' AND tbl_person.bio LIKE '%geology%'
```

Answer (score 1):

try fulltext searching which will give you more functionality and better performance

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

[Any way to achieve fulltext-like search on InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732067/complex-query-for-recreating-fulltext-search-effect-on-innodb/4732982#4732982)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl_person
WHERE
  bio LIKE '%cambridge%'
AND
  bio LIKE '%geology%'
```

You will generate all the `LIKE` clauses for the `WHERE` clause in your program based on the search your user did, then `AND` them together to create the query.

Comment: Nice one, Just what Im looking for. I cannot understand the MySQL reference library all the time. Thanks alot