# Keyword researchs in innoDB MySQL

Tags: mysql, search, innodb

**Problem**: I have a table containing "keywords" associated to a "label".
I have to find the label associated to an input string thanks to a query.

**Example**:

```
DB (table):
keywords| label     | weight
PLOP    | ploplabel | 12
PLOP    | ploplbl   | 8
TOTO    | totolabel | 4
...     | ...       | ...
```

Input string : "PLOP 123"

Should return: "ploplabel"

The first instinctive query in my mind, for partial keywords reasearch, was:

```sql
SELECT label FROM table WHERE keywords LIKE "%inputstring%" ORDER BY weight DESC
```

But as you may have seen, it is the opposite I would need, something like:

```sql
SELECT label FROM table WHERE %keywords% LIKE "inputstring" ORDER BY weight DESC
```

Is it something we can do in MySQL (innoDB === no fulltext)?

Comment: `WHERE %keywords%` is typically WRONG

Comment: Mmh... sorry if I wasn't clear. Of course it's wrong, what I meant is that I was looking for a query having this behavior. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Build your system using innodb and create a myisam fulltext table to index back into your innodb data. That way you get all the advantages of the innodb engine: clustered primary key indexes, row level locking and transactions supplemented by the fulltext capabilities of one or more myisam tables.

[Any way to achieve fulltext-like search on InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732067/complex-query-for-recreating-fulltext-search-effect-on-innodb/4732982#4732982)

Comment: So I do have to create a MyIsam table and fill it with batches...
I really really hoped there was another way.
Thanks f00 !