# MySQL table not supporting FULLTEXT index

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

I am using MySQL with InnoDB engine for my website. While creating a table with FULLTEXT index, it is throwing an error:

**"The used table type doesn't support fulltext indexs"**

What are the alternatives I can use? I don't want to use MyISAM because InnoDB is more advanced. Any way to remove this error?

I am using PHP, MySQL, Apache on Windows machine.

Comment: the following answer may be of interest

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732067/complex-query-for-recreating-fulltext-search-effect-on-innodb/4732982#4732982

Answer (score 4):

FULLTEXT indexes are only supported by the MyISAM engine ; so, if you want your table to be in InnoDB, you won't have much of a choice.

If fulltext searching is an important part of your website/application, you might want to use something else than database, for the indexing/searching part -- typically, some dedicated solution, like [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Comment: Hi Pascal, thanks for the answer. Are there any alternatives available?

Comment: this is not true anymore.Starting with MySql 5.6 you have fulltext search on Innodb too. See http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2011/07/innodb-full-text-search-tutorial/

Comment: Given that 5.6 GE is not out yet, I'd say Pascal's statement still holds true ;)

Answer (score 3):

Wait until MySQL 5.6 - InnoDB is going to support FULLTEXT searches since then ;)

But if you can't wait, you can use for example [SphinxSE](http://www.howtoforge.com/sphinx-as-mysql-storage-engine-sphinxse), which lets you use Sphinx fulltext search engine on your MySQL tables with plain SQL

Comment: Within six months I'd say (given how 5.5 had been released). I have no real information about that though.