# InnoDB Full Text Searches

Tags: java, mysql, lucene, full-text-search, innodb

I have never used full text searching and in starting to learn how to do so am coming across all sorts of pages and articles stating the facts about how full text searching is only available on myisam and what a bad choice that is etc etc.

I've also come across various articles stating that full text searching is now available with innodb based on fulltext search indexes. Unfortunately most of this language is foreign to me at the moment so forgive my ignorance. Is full text searching actually available on innodb? If so, is that a better alternative than a 3rd party such as lucene?

And with all that being said, would anyone care to share some references to some tutorial based articles for full text searching with innodb and Java?

Comment: this answer might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732067/complex-query-for-recreating-fulltext-search-effect-on-innodb/4732982#4732982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know FULLTEXT indexes are only available for InnoDB from MySQL 5.6.

I've wondered about this myself for a while. So I looked at what the [MySQL 5.5 documentation on creating indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html) has to say about FULLTEXT indexes:

> FULLTEXT indexes are supported only for MyISAM tables and can include
>   only CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT columns.

and compared it with what the [MySQL 5.6 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html) has to say about the same subject:

> FULLTEXT indexes are supported only for InnoDB and MyISAM tables and
>   can include only CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT columns.

Seems to me like the choice is either an upgrade to 5.6 or using some kind of workaround!